# UIWebView and local css file

Tags: css, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I want to style a web page meant for the desktop so that it is presentable on a UIWebView on iPhone. I do not have access to the web server from which the pages originate. I would like to do this by changing the `href` attribute of the `<link>` stylesheet element programmatically.

I do the following with my `IBOutlet UIWebView *webView`.

```
NSString *cssPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyStyleSheet" 
                                                    ofType:@"css"];
NSString *js = @"document.getElementsByTagName('link').setAttribute('href','";
NSString *js2 = [js stringByAppendingString:cssPath];
NSString *finalJS = [js2 stringByAppendingString:@"');"];

//check element structure
NSString *res = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:finalJS];
```

This does not work. Using the `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]` message and making a change to the `backgroundColor` of the body does indeed work - done as an exercise to see if I was using the call correctly.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 26):

You can load CSS from local project directory

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

detail info check this site : 
http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/uiwebview-revisited

Comment: The css file is loaded by a declaration in the html header - like this: `<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` Then you need to set the `baseURL` to the directory where the `default.css` file can be found.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately `UIWebView` doesn't provide an API for intercepting *and modifying* the requests that it makes while loading a resource. This means that any approach you try will be hack-ish to a certain extent.

The first approach I would try is:

- Provide your own `UIWebViewDelegate` delegate on the view.
- Implement `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and return `NO` when you spot the CSS requests being made.
- Once the view has finished loading the main resource, use `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to inject JavaScript into the page that dynamically loads/sets the stylesheet that you want to use.

In the JavaScript I would create an entirely new `<link>` element/node on the document instead of trying to modify the existing one.

Comment: I don't think that `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` will be called when loading a css resource.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work, if you choose index 0 of the found elements:

```
    NSString *js = @"document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].setAttribute('href','";
    NSString *js2 = [js stringByAppendingString:cssPath];
    NSString *finalJS = [js2 stringByAppendingString:@"');"];
    [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:finalJS];
```

You missed [0]

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 3**

If you (like me) only use a html snippet (not a complete web page) you need to add your local css file in the header of the html snippet.

I therefore define a html header like this:

```
let htmlHeader = "<html> \n <head> \n <link href=\"default.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" /> \n </head> \n <body> \n"
```

and a footer like this:

```
let htmlFooter = "</body> \n </html>"
```

Then find the baseURL for the css like this:

```
let baseURLForCss = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "css")
```

And load the html snippet with your own css like this:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(String.init(format: "%@%@&@", htmlHeader, htmlSnippet, htmlFooter), baseURL: baseURLForCss)
```