# what is the wrong when loading local resource files in webview in iphone

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, css, uiwebview

I am trying to load local css and html files into WebView , but the web view displays the content of css file in webview as you see in the following image ..

## objective-c code:

```
NSString *htmlPath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"  inDirectory:NO];
//[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath]]];

// load css styles
NSString *cssPath   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"css" ofType:@"css"];
NSData *cssData     = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cssPath];
NSString *cssString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cssData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// load js
NSString *jsPath   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyJS" ofType:@"js"];
NSData *jsData     = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsPath];
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];                         

// compose full html page
NSString *pageContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", cssString, jsString, htmlPath];
[webView loadHTMLString:pageContent baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

[image: screen shot]

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You must not use

```
          [webView loadHTMLString:pageContent baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

instead loadHTMLString try to use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

And if you have any problem check the following post. I think you will get it easily

[UIWebView and local css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032159/uiwebview-and-local-css-file)

I have not used it for CSS but hope this will help you...Good Luck...

Comment: can you show an example how to use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString ?

Comment: NSString *js = @"document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].setAttribute('href','";
    NSString *js2 = [js stringByAppendingString:cssPath];
    NSString *finalJS = [js2 stringByAppendingString:@"');"];
    [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:finalJS]; Actually this code is from the link I have given...Please check the link its so much helpful.....

Comment: but when the HTML is loaded ?!