# UIWebView baseURL and absolute path

Tags: html, uiwebview, base-url

I have an HTML page that is constructed like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

It is stored in my documents directory:

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/12345-ID/Documents/mysite/index.html
```

I have also stored the style.css in the documents directory:

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/12345-ID/Documents/mysite/style.css
```

But now, when I try to load the html into my webview using this:

```
NSURL *test = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/12345-ID/Documents/mysite/"]
[myWebView loadHTMLString:<the content retrieved from index.html> baseURL:test];
```

The css is not loaded, when I intercept the request to the stylesheet with a NSURLProtocol I can see the request is wrong. It is trying to request:

> file:///style.css

instead of the full baseURL. Now I can solve this by removing the / in front of /style.css in the html file. But is there an easy way to resolve this in native code without modifying the html?

Comment: That is exactly what I am using (see content)

Comment: Have you tried taking the '/' off of the end of the NSURL *test = [NSURL ....... line. You may have a double slash condition occuring, which may be causing it to default to the user location, just a thought.

Comment: OK in a last attempt, try the answer I have provided.  It should work, as I have used this method in my own apps to display tons of images using relative paths.  The only difference is in my HTML I don't have the slash in front of the filename, which does mean that your "/style.css" would have to change to "style.css".  Is there a reason you are so against that???

Comment: No there is not a particular reason I am against removing the / in front, but the HTML is not created by me. So I wanted to see if there was a way to solve this in native so I would have to bother the creator to remove the /

Comment: Sidenote: You can get a local URI using `pathForResource:ofType:` from `NSBundle` and then reference using `file://<local_uri>` in your own HTML. For example, for `jquery-2.1.1.min.js`, I use: `NSString *jQueryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jquery-2.1.1.min" ofType:@"js"]; NSString *jQueryUri = [@"file://" stringByAppendingString:jQueryFile];` and then I simply add it to my HTML: `NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<some_html><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"%@\"></script></some_html>", jQueryUri];`. Finally: `[myWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the slash was the only solution

Comment: But you'll have a problem once the app goes live and no longer resides in the simulator at that specific path... trumpetlicks solution is valid regardless of app location.

Comment: It should be possible to still use absolute paths in webview. You need to implement custom NSURLProtocol. Although it requires a lot of code so i'm looking for an easy way to handle this. Once i find it. I'll post it here.

Answer (score 12):

Generate your path and base url the following way:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

A great blog on the subject:

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/uiwebview-revisited

A SO QA on the subject

[UIWebView and local css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032159/uiwebview-and-local-css-file)

Comment: Removing the slash was the only solution, still thanks very much for at least trying to help :)

Comment: I somewhat thought that was going to be be the case, but until you try the combinations......  Sorry there wasn't a solution that fit your needs.