# Is it possible to have ressources in folders (and not groups) to use with storyboard IB?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, directory

I have a folder structure which I cannot convert to groups (as folders are accessed from html pages).
Currently under IB, I can pick an image which I see on the view controller, but when executing, I've got the error the image could not load.
Any idea?

[EDIT 1] I was not clear actually: the same resources are shared between the web app html files AND the native code with usual IB views.

[EDIT 2] The actual error message is as follows: 
Could not load the "Kobras-018-.jpg" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.drpouille.Corn2"

Comment: Did you set the baseURL for your HTML? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235207/uiwebview-baseurl

Comment: I was not clear actually: the same resources are shared between the Web app html files AND the native code with usual IB views. @troop231