# UIWebView can't find local images

Tags: ios, uiwebview

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                    error:nil];
myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

My code is like this. In index.html, I have

```
<img src="dog.gif"/>
<h1>index.html loaded</h1>
```

Both the index.html and dog.gif are stored in the PROJECT_ROOT/Resources/.
But my app works OK on the simulator, but fails to load dog.gif on my iPad. The  text is showed on both. I cleaned the project, but that didn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately iOS does not support GIF images, also you cannot use them for animations. If you use GIF images, the imageview will show the first frame of that image, nothing more.

Please refer UIImage for the supported formats.

Comment: i think you baseURL is incorrect. Try to change to NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]; For more information please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235207/uiwebview-baseurl