# I am facing a weird issue with UIWebview object in IOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, swift3

I m facing a weird issue with UIWebview object. here i have to load html page with css file and js.here is the below lines of code i used

```
let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sale", ofType: "html")
let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!,encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)         
webViewObj.loadHTMLString(html!,baseURL: nil)

it only loads the html page on device and IOS simulator (no css and JS applied ).

Where as the same html file loads well on Android device with applied css and JS.

Please suggest any workaround.
```

Comment: You should set baseUrl. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032159/uiwebview-and-local-css-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your sale.html, the css file should write like this:

```
<link href="mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Pay attention to the "href".

Add baseurl when load html source:

```
let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sale", ofType: "html")
let baseURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath)
let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!,encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
webViewObj.loadHTMLString(html!,baseURL: baseURL)
```

If it not work, you can use Safari to debug the sale.html. Or you can print the path of sale.html and open the path in Finder. Just figure out where the css and js file, then change the "href" to the right path.

You may be want to see this: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

Comment: I replaced html code with your given line but still same issue is occuring.

Comment: And in Device Safari Browser same html file is working fine.

Comment: @SanketPund can you put css line of the original sale.html ?

Comment: Yes Sure.
Below are list of css files which are using in html.

<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">
<link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">
<link href="css/demo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="css/chardinjs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: try these code:`<link href="./font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="./bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="./datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="./layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="./demo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="./chardinjs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">` When app runing, the css directory do not created. So you need change "css" to relative directory.

Comment: I have already did this and also used absolute path for the same but nothing working and I also used your code but it's also not working .

Comment: @SanketPund Add the baseURL when loading html. I have updated my answer.